# OracleConnectionStringBuilder throw exception

Tags: c#, exception, server, oracleclient

I wrote my application, which should work with Oracle DB. I use Oracle.DataAccess for it. In my developer's PC everything work great, without any problem, but in the server I have:

Exception Message:

> 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionStringBuilder' threw an
>   exception."

Inner Exception Message:

> "The provider is not compatible
>   with the version of Oracle client"*.`

Version of Oracle client in my PC and server is the same (11.2.0). I tried to build my application to x86, x64 and Any CPU (server is x64 and my PC is x64), but no effect.

I tried to write simple application, which contain only using OracleConnectionStringBuilder and OracleConnection and it work without any problem in this server.

Code in my main application:

```
public DatabaseProcessor(string ConnectionString)
        {
            OracleConnectionStringBuilder ocsb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
            this.Connection = new OracleConnection(ocsb.ToString());
        }
```

Code in my test application, which work without problem:

```
OracleConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder(connectionData);
                OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString.ToString());
                connection.Open();
                connection.Clone();
```

Can anybody tell me, whats wrong and how I can run my application on this server?

Comment: Without looking at the code we'll be guessing. I suggest you post the relvant code

Comment: I added code part from my application with problem and from test application.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the GAC?

Comment: In event viewer I have messages: "Application: app.exe
Framework Version:v4.0.30319
Description:The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(System.String)   at Company.DatabaseLib.DatabaseProcessor..ctor(System.String)
   at app.Program.Main(System.String[])" and then: "Faulting application name: app.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54e5efa8
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x53159a86Exception code: 0xe0434352"

Comment: I can not understand why, but after I create new solution, "copy-paste" all my lib projects to new solution, "copy-paste" all code and compile new solution, program start on the server without any problem, but in my PC I have the same error, which was in the server before.